# grafana variables in panel

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Could you please explane me what does `$instance` mean in expression:

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance=~"$instance"}[$interval])) * 100) * ON(instance)
```

and why i see `No data points`

but when I change `$instance` to `.*`
graph was shown.

in prometheus I see than `node_cpu_seconds_total` return data like this:

```
✔node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu="1",instance="10.0.97.140:9100",job="node-exporter",mode="idle"}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are variables coming from the Grafana templating feature.

Two notations exist:

- `$variable`
- `[[variable]]`

More information in the Grafana docs: https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/

The reason you don't see any values in your example is simple: The variable is not defined as a template variable. If you change it to `.*` you simply allow any value as a regular expression.

Comment: In dashboard settings I found Variables, thank you.